# Сформировать массив С из массива Х без повторений

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Изначально задача звучит так:

> Сформировать массив С из чисел, которые входят в массив
>   Х, но при этом не входят в массив Y
>   (без повторения), отсортировать массив С и вывести его на экран.

Допустим дан массив X {3, 2, 2, 3}, который уже прогнан через функцию findNum (с этим тоже проблем нет). Нужно сформировать массив C из чисел массива X без повторений, то есть, в данном случае, массив С должен получиться {3, 2} (массив сортируется по убыванию, но с этим проблем нет).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблемы возникают, когда массив X {3, 2, 3, 2} или же {2, 3, 2, 3}, то есть, когда числа в массиве через один. В этом случае так же массив должен быть {3, 2}, но возникает лишняя цифра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Массив Х изначально сортировать нельзя.

Подскажите, что можно с этим сделать?

```
for (int i = 1, last = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!findNum(Y, X[i], m)) {
        if (last == X[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        last = X[i];
        C[size++] = X[i];
    }
}
```

Где функция findNum:

```
bool findNum(const int *Y, int num, int m) {
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (num == Y[j]) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

Полный код программы, если нужно: https://anotepad.com/notes/3n2mj8

Comment: 'last' поменяйте на проверку 'findNum'. Сейчас проверяются только дублирующиеся числа идущие подряд. А функция гарантирует проверку вхождения чисел в любом порядке.

Comment: @andrey-sv, боже, это гениально

Answer (score 2):

Проходите по массиву `X`, и проверяете каждый его элемент на вхождение в `Y`. Входит - значит, идем дальше. Не входит? Проверяем, не было ли **раньше** такого элемента в `X`, т.е. сравнением с элементами до текущего. Был? идем дальше. Нет? пишем в `C` и идем дальше.

Неэффективно, понятно, но для вас, как я понимаю, это не важно.

Код сами напишете?

Еще вариант - записывать в `C` с повторами, потом отсортировать `C` и выбросить лишнее.

Comment: То есть добавить вложенный цикл, который бы проходил по всем элементам и сравнивал?

Comment: С, к сожалению, должен сразу формироваться без повторений.

Comment: Откуда я знаю, что с чем вы сравнивать собираетесь?... Не могу вам ответить ни да, ни нет.

Comment: Ну так пишите сразу **все** условия. Вы писали только *"Массив Х изначально сортировать нельзя."* Про `C` и `Y` ничего не говорилось. Это непорядочно по отношению к тем, кто читает задачи - часто бывает так, что люди трудятся, находят решение, а потом эдакое "что вы мне пишете? так и так нельзя из-за таких-то ограничений". Это не к нынешней ситуации, а на будущее. При неполном ТЗ результат один - ХЗ.